# Unable to resume from suspend due to zsh as default shell - why?

Tags: bash, suspend, power-management, zsh

I've been bothered by a problem where my workstation won't resume from suspend. When the PC is powered the power button is fully lit, and when it's suspended the button is blinking. Pressing the power button did not wake up the PC, nor did any input with the wired keyboard/mouse, as it should have. The only way to recover was to hold down the power button and do a hard shutdown.

My computer specs:

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- GNOME 42.9 / X11
- ASUS Prime X299-A II motherboard
- Linux Kernel 6.2.0-32-generic

I noticed that the computer *was* able to resume from suspend when logged in as a different user. What I eventually found was this:

```sh
➜  ~ cat /etc/passwd | grep "jim|blair"
jim:x:1000:1000:Jim,,,:/home/jim:/bin/bash
blair:x:1001:1002:Blair,,,:/home/blair:/usr/bin/zsh
```

The `jim` account was resuming just fine, and the `blair` account was not. So simply changing my default shell to bash (`sudo chsh -s /bin/bash`) fixed the problem.

My question is WHY? What is it about zsh as opposed to bash that makes it so my computer can't wake up? Is this a bug that should be reported somewhere, and if so, to whom? Is it a problem with zsh, Ubuntu, the linux kernel, my BIOS configuration, or something else?

This problem is "solved" in the sense that I fixed the errant behavior, but I'd like to understand it a bit deeper - appreciate any insight, and at the very least maybe this will help someone with the same problem.

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/zsh` in your `/etc/shells` file? It's not considered a "valid" shell by the authentication system if it's not. Do: `echo "/usr/bin/zsh" | sudo tee -a /etc/shells` to add it.

Comment: Yup, it's in there, and it was in there before. Good information though, thank you!